# Signal R Querystring not passing

Tags: c#, signalr

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here... I'm building a simple Notification system for a multi-user portal and trying to use Signal R to accomplish the Push notification.

I am able to establish a connection and push notifications out to ALL users fine enough, but to target the specific user to show the notification to I need to track User ID and map that to a connectionId on the server. To achieve this I am passing an encrypted string of the user's ID to the server and storing a list of objects that stores the user's ID to the created Connection ID. However, when trying to pass the encrypted UserID as a Query string it won't pass it through. Any ideas where I'm messsing up here?

**Javascript**

```
/////Connect to NotificationHub

var nHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection.notificationHub.qs = { "userId": "1A3BCF" };

////Register Add Notification Method
nHub.client.showNotification = function (message, icon, url) {
    console.log("Notification Received!");
    console.log("Message: " + message);
    console.log("Icon: " + icon);
    console.log("URL: " + url);
};

$.connection.hub.start()
.done(function () {

    console.log("Successful Connection to Notification Hub");

})
.fail(function () {
    console.log("Error Connecting to Notification Hub!");
});
```

**C# Hub**

```
List<NotificationConnection> connectedUsers = new List<NotificationConnection>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var us = new NotificationConnection();
        us.userId= Context.QueryString['userId'];;
        us.connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        connectedUsers.Add(us);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public void showNotification(NotificationTargetType target, int objectId, string message, string icon, string url)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

        if (target == NotificationTargetType.User)
        {
            var user = connectedUsers.Where(o => o.userId== objectId);
            if (user.Any())
            {
                hubContext.Clients.Client(user.First().connectionId).showNotification(message, icon, url);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
```

Again everything goes through smoothly until I want to grab the Querystring, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try setting qs on connection and not the hub.

Comment: Is this a typo: `Context.QueryString['userId'];`? It should be double quotes

Comment: @Pawel You led me down the right path. Thank you. I've added the change below

Answer (score 1):

As Pawel mentioned I was adding qs to the wrong item. Needed to call it on the connection.hub instead of the actual hub.

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { "userId": "1A3BCF" };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer has helped me to understand how to send the second parameter via query string, conventional {hub.qs="key=value"} confusing me to pass second query string params and this json format actually helped. Thanks @Seth Duncan. Cheers